# jQuery validation plugin rule for value in group or in array

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a jQuery validation rule to ensure that `access_id` is either 5, 6, or 8?  I suppose I could create my own rule called `inArray`, but would rather use a supported rule if it exists.

```
{
   "rules":{
      "access_id":{
         "inArray":[5,6,8]
      }
   }
}


$.validator.addMethod("inArray", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value in params);
    }, "Not an allowed selection.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a jQuery validation rule to ensure that access_id is either 5, 6, or 8?

No, there is no such rule. You will need to write your own [as you've already outlined](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

In the future, you could simply look at the script and see the rules for yourself.  The code comments on some of them explain usage.  They're within the `methods` object towards the end of the script, and the `additional-methods` file is nothing but more rules.

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js

Comment: Thanks Sparky,  I did spend some time reviewing the existing rules.  I was a little surprised that this one didn't exist.  That being said, it is very easy to add a rule, so not a big deal.